# Click on background image and download the image from the link and show process bar javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a dummy image

```
<a href="http://example.com/filename"><img src="dummy.jpg"></a>
```

On click that dummy image, i need to download the file which is on third party server. that file might be image or mp4 file.

while downloading in need to show process bar which shows the downloading percentage

Comment: That is it ? Anything else ?

Comment: Post your code. Show us what you have already tried.

Answer (score 0):

To download a file directly after click use download attribute

```
<a href="http://example.com/filename" download>
    <img src="dummy.jpg">
</a>
```

If you want to rename the file, then you can use a value with download attribute

```
<a href="http://example.com/filename" download="new_file_name">
    <img src="dummy.jpg">
</a>
```